# Can you recommend a free Task Board/Burndown tool for Windows?

Tags: agile

There's not a lot to add to the subject really.

I am after a free task board/ burndown reporting tool for Windows.

Comment: Waffle.IO: I recommend it because it's a taskboard that integrates with GitHub

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're willing to host your tool,

- TargetProcess
  ([http://www.targetprocess.com/](http://www.targetprocess.com/Product/agile_tour.aspx))
- XPlanner(http://xplanner.codehaus.org/)

If not,

- Pivotal Tracker (http://www.pivotaltracker.com/)
- ScrumWorks (http://danube.com/scrumworks/basic)

All are either free or have a free version.

Comment: Unfortunately https://www.targetprocess.com/Product/agile_tour.aspx  Not Working

Comment: Waffle.IO integrates with GitHub

Comment: Wow xplanner is soooo dead (and really outdated and not really user friendly) :-)

(to avoid confusion: I understand that this answer is old and apparently had its right to exist in 2008. But I'm migrating a project from xplanner to GitLab a.t.m. and I stumbled upon this - just had to comment. Please forgive me.)

Comment: these tools and not free anymore. so the answer is obsolete

Answer (score 15):

Depending on your real needs, solutions range from :

- hand-written cards complemented with a manually drawn burndown chart as [big visible chart](http://xprogramming.com/articles/bigvisiblecharts/)  as recommend by Ilja
- spreadsheet-based list with automatic burndown graph generation ([example](http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/scrum/simple-sprint-backlog))
- online tools such as [scrumy](http://scrumy.com/), [scrumpad](http://www.scrumpad.com/) and  [skinnyboard](http://skinnyboard.com/)
- local application with web access

  - free [ScrumWorks basic](http://www.danube.com/scrumworks/basic), [Icescrum2](http://www.icescrum.org)
  - or commercial [ScrumWorks Pro](http://www.danube.com/scrumworks/pro) [ProjectCards](http://www.projectcards.com/), or, as Eliza recommended,  [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com/Product.aspx)

Remember however the [Agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) is recommending to favor "Individuals and interactions over processes and tools".

I'd recommend starting small, perhaps with a spreadsheet if you insist on automatic burndown charting.

Answer (score 6):

Check out SeeNowDo at www.seenowdo.com

It's a free online taskboard for distributed Agile teams.  It's pretty cool and provides convenient features like 'always-on' and 'instant-sync' capability.  It also has some cool ways of managing the taskboard layout once you have alot of tasks on it.  Best of all, it's *completely* free.

Answer (score 4):

**Apparently I got to disclose I built this product**

You might want to try: http://www.burndown-charts.com

It's a free webapp for managing burndown charts. You create a team and a sprint and you are ready to go. Enter your tasks once they are done. Perfect for when you still want to keep a board and/or post-its. You can add teammates to your team if you need.

You're not going to spend an hour figuring out how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly what Scrumy.com is.  It is a whiteboard with sticky notes.  The pro version has a burndown.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/mingle-agile-project-management). It is free for upto 5 users.

Answer (score 3):

Open Source app: http://taskboard.cognifide.com/

Fast, tidy tool :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Ok, we are working on something that does just what you asked and way more:

- Actionable metrics
- Powerful analytics
- All this on a slick Dashboard

It's meant to eliminate the use of excel sheets to build your own reports by hand.
It's a far better solution and it is in beta right now.

Sign up and participate in the beta to make sure your features are well covered!
http://www.in-sight.io

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing more about your situation, I have to *highly* recommend a wall of index cards and a handdrawn chart on flip chart paper. Works much better than any software in the standard situation.

If you really have to use software, there is none that I could recommend unreservedly, let alone a free one. You might want to keep in mind that some of the commercial ones are free for open source or academic projects, too. Which one's right for you will depend, besides other things, on how much you want it to define your process.

Comment: This is for my own projects and wall space is limited so software is really the only way.

Comment: So, you are working alone on those projects? Might be worth to add that information to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating your own solution using a spreadsheet.
That way you get low overhead on data entry and as much reporting capabilities as you want, without having an external tool define your process.

Especially on single-person projects (as this appears to be from the comment on Ilja Preuß's answer), I find that a simple spreadsheet actually works better for me.

I keep all my tasks in one workbook, and the formulas that pull out interesting data and calculations in a separate workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic plugin that can be inserted in google wave and be used as a taskboard. More details in http://agilebooknote.blogspot.com/2009/11/taskboardy-available.html.
Cheers,
-fede

Comment: I actually ended up doing something very similar in using Microsoft's Live service and the on-line Excel version. Since then I've tried many tools but never found anything quite perfect. Still, changing tools keeps everything fresh and opens up new ideas about how to track my projects :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of google docs because of the simplicity and also because I can give access to my team so that they can update their tasks on a daily basis.  The template I use and a tutorial on how to use it is available at

[Burn Down Chart Tutorial: Simple Agile Project Tracking](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/burn-down-charts-tutorial-simple-agile-project-tracking/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old thread, but I came across this question looking for something similar. I signed up for AgileZen (http://www.agilezen.com/) and it's actually quite good.

I wanted something free that my wife and I could use for personal/home stuff. It's free if you're willing to have only one project (I call it "Home") and one other collaborator (my wife). It's a pretty good solution for us.

I promise I have no affiliation with them! Except that I now use their product.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is open source, non-profit or a classroom you can get free access to Atlassians' JIRA + Greenhopper (and other tools) for agile project management. Otherwise small teams can get access for a nominal fee.

see http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/overview and http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview.

See http://www.atlassian.com/software/views/open-source-license-request if your an open source project.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/views/community-license-request if you are a non-profit

and

http://www.atlassian.com/survey/classroom-license-request if your a classroom.